# PC wakes itself immediately after being turned off or put to sleep

Tags: windows, sleep, power, power-management, wake-up

My Windows 8.1 computer wakes up immediately after being put to sleep (either of the sleep options in the start menu.) So I spent some time trying to understand the problem, read multiple posts here with similar issues, but got nowhere, so posting this.

The weirdest phenomenon is that when I click "turn off" from the start menu (loosely translated as the Windows language is not English), the computer shuts down, but then immediately turns itself back on! Likewise when I turn the PC off using the hardware power-button, it shuts downs (I get a normal blue screen saying "windows is powering off") but then immediately the PC powers back up.

I ran "powercfg -lastwake", and found no clues. When powering up from software or hardware power-down, its says:
*Wake History Count - 0*

When powering up from sleep it says:
*Wake History Count - 1

Wake History [0]

   Wake Source Count - 0*

What does that mean?

In device manager I unticked "allow this device to wakeup computer" for the mouse and keyboard (just to rule this out, as eventually I do want these to wake up the computer). I unticked wakeup option for the LAN card (unticked magic packet too).

I tried to look at Event Viewer, I found a Power-Troubleshooter event from the time I sent the computer to sleep, that says the system went to sleep for about 1 minute, wakeup source unknown. I'm sure I haven't exhausted Event Viewer possibilities, **what should I filter for in Event Viewer?**

I checked task manager, there are no tasks. I think task wakeup isn't likely since self- power-up happens immediately each time regardless If I do sleep or power-down.

BIOS of this PC is far from being the most updated version, **do you recommend updating the BIOS?** The computer is rather ancient, Intel DP35DP, the BIOS documentation recommends not to update unless your particular issue appears in their updates/fixes lists, to avoid new issues. So that made me a bit reluctant to update.

Another thing: in control panel, power options, advanced, under the options for "sleep", I set "wakeup timers" to "not available" (loosely translated).

**Any help will be greatly appreciated.**

Comment: Did you check wake-on-ring settings in your BIOS?

Comment: In BIOS I have:
after power failure - stay off
wake on lan from s5 - stay off
acpi suspend state - s3 state
eist - enable
c2 state - disable
wake system from s5 - disable

Comment: I have precisely the same problem, with brand-new, expensive, modern hardware and the latest version of Windows 10. What's so strange is that it's a transient condition; despite the fact that the machine wakes-up *immediately* if I try to put it to sleep (i.e., it probably never goes to sleep, technically), I come down in the morning to find it asleep! So, it seems, rather definitively, that something is preventing the computer from being put to sleep manually around the time that I normally go to bed. I do have a few Task Scheduler jobs, but none of them should (in theory) be causing this...

Answer (score 0):

In my case I disabled Windows Media Player's DLNA server and that worked.

Comment: Going to Explorer->computer tab->disable DLNA service-(-ish), I see it is not enabled. Likewise in "media sharing center" DLNA is not enabled. I disabled Windows DLNA Network Service in Services for good measure, but this didn't solve the problem. Actually this PC was not online at the time of the experiments, I connected it now just to make sure there was no other obscure cause, but the results are the same. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Windows can't turn your PC back on after shutdown. My guess is:

> 1. A virus, or a 3rd party software changed the behavior of ***Sleep*** and ***Shutdown*** software buttons to ***Restart*** your computer instead. **(Unlikely condition)**

To make sure if the problem resides in your OS, try to boot from a live CD like windows or linux. You can also accomplish this goal using a Windows Installation Disk (Windows 7 and above).

- Boot from the installation disk
- After seeing the "Choose Input Language" box, press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>F10</kbd> to open command line.
- type `wpeutil shutdown` and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Now, your computer shutsdown. If it stays off, then there's a problem with your windows (software problem). A fresh installation of windows must do the job for you. But, if it turns back on, then:

> 2. There's a hardware problem with your motherboard/Power module or the power button sends PowerOn signal to your motherboard continuously. **(Most Likely)**

In this case, you have to visit a hardware technician to repair your motherboard/power module, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes ACPI drivers won't work well on old machines running newer Windows versions. Try disable "Fast Startup" setting under "Power options", that solved problems on some of my clients.